# $G$ be a finite group, if $H\lneq G$ and $|G| \nmid [G:H]!$. Prove $G$ is not simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

> Let G be a finite group, if $H\lneq G$ and $|G| \nmid ( \, [G:H]! \, ) $ then prove $G$ is not simple.

I used contrapositive argument. Suppose $G$ is simple then we need to prove that $ |G| \mid ( \, [G:H]! \, ) $. Now consider the group action $$f:G\times G/H \rightarrow G/H \\ (g,xH) \mapsto (gxH)$$

Note that it is not necessary for $H$ to be a normal subgroup of $G$. This group action is equivalent to a homomorphism $\phi : G \rightarrow S(G/H)$. Then $K=Ker(\phi) \trianglelefteq G$. If $K={1}$ then $|G|$ divides $|S(G/H)|=[G:H]!$ .  Now i am not sure how i can exclude the case of $K=G$. Any hints ?

Comment: Your action is not trivial, so $\phi$ is not trivial and $K\neq G$.

Comment: If $K=G$, then there is only one coset in $[G:H]$, namely $H$ itself. So $H = G$.

Comment: See the proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1307215/if-h-leq-g-and-gh-leq-g-then-g-is-not-simple?rq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3035390/h-is-a-subgroup-of-a-finite-group-g-such-that-h-and-biggh-1-big?rq=1).

Comment: Thanks i got it :)

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88719/a-group-g-with-a-subgroup-h-of-index-n-has-a-normal-subgroup-k-subset-h